# Sequentially click each element and wait between each click

Tags: javascript

I have a `querySelectorAll` list that looks something like this:

```
NodeList(676) [div.tile.tooltip, div.tile.tooltip, div.tile.tooltip.tooltipstered,
 div.tile.tooltip, div.tile.tooltip, div.tile.tooltip, div.tile.tooltip,
 div.tile.tooltip.tooltipstered, div.tile.tooltip.tooltipstered, div.tile.tooltip,
 div.tile.tooltip, div.tile.tooltip.tooltipstered,  ...
```

each is a widget I can click on in the site, however, I wanted to click on each but with a timer to delay each click by a few seconds. I have attempted the following:

```
var tile = document.querySelectorAll(".perspectivesInner.clearFix > div");
var t = new Array();
for( let i = 0 ; i < tile.length ; i++ ) {
    (function(){    // create a closure (new scope)
      var _i = i;   // make a local copy of `i` from the outer scope
      t[i] = setTimeout( function(){return tile[i].click()}, i*2000 );
    })();
  }
```

This clicks on everything, but I get logged to the console:

> VM2642:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'click')
> at :5:52

What is the clean alternative?

Comment: You are using `let` so, there is no need for a closure, even if there was, that is not how you make a closure. Why are you defining `_i` if it is never used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more ES6 way to write this that resolves your issue.

```js
let tiles = document.querySelectorAll(".perspectivesInner.clearFix > div");
tiles.forEach((tile,i) => {
  setTimeout(() => tile.click(), i * 1000);
});
```

```html
<div class="perspectivesInner clearFix">
  <div onclick="console.log(this.innerText)">One</div>
  <div onclick="console.log(this.innerText)">Two</div>
  <div onclick="console.log(this.innerText)">Three</div>
  <div onclick="console.log(this.innerText)">Four</div>
  <div onclick="console.log(this.innerText)">Five</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this pretty clean with `Promises`

Using a async wait method you can wait a random time between each click like that

```js
// #region utility
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

async function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
// #endregion

async function clickElements(selector) {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  for (const element of elements) {
    element.click();
    await wait(randomIntFromInterval(1000, 2000));
  }
}

clickElements('.perspectivesInner.clearFix > div');
```

```html
<div class="perspectivesInner clearFix">
  <div class="perspective" onclick="console.log('0')">0</div>
  <div class="perspective" onclick="console.log('1')">1</div>
  <div class="perspective" onclick="console.log('2')">2</div>
  <div class="perspective" onclick="console.log('3')">3</div>
  <div class="perspective" onclick="console.log('4')">4</div>
  <div class="perspective" onclick="console.log('5')">5</div>
  <div class="perspective" onclick="console.log('6')">6</div>
  <div class="perspective" onclick="console.log('7')">7</div>
  <div class="perspective" onclick="console.log('8')">8</div>
  <div class="perspective" onclick="console.log('9')">9</div>
</div>
```